# R: How to turn a matrix of values into a function

Tags: r

I have a `n x m` matrix of values. In this toy example, suppose `n = m = 3`.

```
mymat <- matrix(c(16, -15, -2, 15, 13, 16, 0, 0, 0.42), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
> mymat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   16   15 0.00
[2,]  -15   13 0.00
[3,]   -2   16 0.42
```

My goal is to create the following function, where the input `x` is a length `m - 1` vector. The goal is to return `n` values where I multiply the first `m-1` columns of `mymat` by the `m-1` entries in the input `x`. Then I'll add the value in the `m`th column of `mymat`. The function is as follows:

```
 myfun <- function(x){
   vec1 <- 16 * x[1] + 15* x[2]
   vec2 <- -15 * x[1] + 13 * x[2] 
   vec3 <- -2 * x[1] + 16 * x[2] + 0.42
   return(c(vec1, vec2, vec3))
 }
```

However, it's very tedious to construct this function if `mymat`'s dimension grows. Is there a more efficient way to code this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is matrix multiplication, if you add a `1` to the end of `x`.

Here's your function:

```
foo = function(x, mat) {
  c(mat %*% c(x, 1))
}
```

Demonstration:

```
all(myfun(1:2) == foo(1:2, mymat))
# [1] TRUE

all(myfun(3:4) == foo(3:4, mymat))
# [1] TRUE
```